# When I should add the word "class" creating pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, class, elaborated-type-specifier

In what cases it could be invalid to write `Type *p = nullptr;`

whereas only
`class Type *p = nullptr;` is satisfying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need it when the type `Type` is shadowed by the name of a variable:

```
class Type{};

int main() {
    int Type = 42;

    //Type * p = nullptr; // error: 'p' was not declared in this scope
    class Type* p = nullptr;
}
```

However, as pointed out by Ayxan Haqverdili, `::Type* p = nullptr;` works as well and has the added benefit of also working with type aliases.

Comment: Like in order to specify that it must be a pointer to object of a class but not to a plain type?

Comment: This I didn't know.

Comment: @MaxPopovsky `Type * p` means: multiply the `int` called `Type` with some `p`, but there is no `p` in scope. And next error would be that you cannot assign `nullptr` to the result of that multiplication

Comment: @MaxPopovsky actually I have no clue how to do it when `class Type{};` is replaced with `using Type = int;`

Comment: @463035818 you could do `::Type`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili you just saved me from posting a very silly question :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to another answer, an [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) forward declares a name, so you can write:

```
// class Type1 {};
Type1 *p = nullptr;         // error: 'Type1' was not declared in this scope

// class Type2 {};
class Type2 *p = nullptr;   // compiles
```

This could also be useful when you declare functions in headers:

```
void foo(class Type*);   // no separate forward declaration of Type is needed
```